# Is there a way to make Python run with Excel automatically?

Tags: python, excel, vba

I am trying to automate an Excel sheet by creating a button. I want that when this button is pressed my Python script should start running and its output should be written back into the Excel sheet.

To make the Python script work, I integrated it with VBA. When the button is clicked, the following code runs:

```
Sub Macro2()
    RetVal = Shell('path to python file', vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

My Python script is very simple:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Prior Example.xlsm')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('UI')
sheet['F10'] = 'hello'
```

However, when I press the button, I do not get any output in F10. Is there something wrong with the code/is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: does your python code work correctly when you call it from the terminal?

Comment: yes it works correctly on the terminal

Comment: To run the command from the command line are you typing `python python_file.py`? because that's not what you're sending the Shell command. If you want to test that you python script is running I would suggest trying to add a file to your desktop in a test script, use the full path e.g. `C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\test_file.txt` if you're on windows.

Comment: No I am using cd /Users/user_name/Desktop and then entering python file name when prompted as Desktop>

Comment: Well, I haven't worked in VBA for awhile, but no one else seems to be working on the problem... Can you trying making a sample script that makes a file on your desktop and see if you're able to run python from VBA? If not, try adding the path to your `python.exe` file in front of the *full* path to your `.py` file.