# Is there a way to integrate python and excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a button on my excel sheet. I want that when the user presses this button, my python script should automatically run. I tried:

```
Sub Macro2()
    RetVal = Shell("F:/Assets/Global/Portfolio/cal.py", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

I am getting a run time error when I press the button. Can someone explain where I am wrong and what I should do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba+python

Comment: Not familiar with integrating Python, but it seems unless `.py` script files are associated with an executable, that `Shell` command isn't running anything. Probably need to shell `python.exe` and pass the script path/filename as an argument.

Comment: Does the `F:/Assets/Global/Portfolio/cal.py` command work if you invoke it from a command-line?

Comment: Yes it works from the command line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make Python run with Excel automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56189812/is-there-a-way-to-make-python-run-with-excel-automatically)

Comment: @Ray234 have you tried `python.exe "path to .py script"`? That would be `Shell "python.exe ""path to .py script""", vbNormalFocus` (don't bother with `RetVal` if you don't care for the return value)